# PDO - rowCount() on update query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So the problem is when i reload the page 2 times quickly, first time `rowCount()` returns `1` and second time it returns me `0`, and thats only when i do that quickly something like interval every `100ms`, but for example if i change interval to `1s` `rowCount()` returns me everytime `1` so no problems.

this is my code

```
$updated = $db->query('update urc set retime=? where a=? and b=? and c=?',[time(),$a,$b,$c]);
echo $updated->rowCount();
```

when i select rows for example it everytime returns me `1`, it works perfectly without any problem

```
$updated = $db->query('select 1 from urc where a=? and b=? and c=?',[$a,$b,$c]);
echo $updated->rowCount();
```

variables `a`,`b` and `c` allways have the same values.

AND i use this class for PDO

```
class PDOSQL{
    private static 
        $username="root",
        $password="",
        $host="127.0.0.1",
        $dbh;
    public function connect($dbname){
        return (self::$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$dbname.";host=".self::$host, self::$username, self::$password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")));
    }
    public function query($sql, $args){
        $stmt = self::$dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

so what is the problem here with my update query or maybe its database problem?
i'm using `innodb` engine for this table.

i hope you understand my problem. sorry for my english.

thank you

Comment: If `time()` is the same there will be nothing to update. Depending on the column you could try http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: `time()` is **not** accurate to 100ms; it's a [UNIX timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 - so it only changes every second, refreshing twice within the same second will result in the same timestamp and nothing will be updated.

Comment: @CD001 yea im so so stupid its logic which idiot will do the same thing twice omg!!! thanks cd001

Comment: @chris85 thanks i got it

Comment: You can always use a [higher precision representation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) if that's important.

Comment: @tadman i have to! thank you ! :)